# Why are my divs acting like I specified a centimeter and a half margin-top/margin-bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, margin

I'm working on an AngularJS app and am experiencing unwanted whitespace.

```
<div class='user' ng-repeat='session in sessions'>
    <div class='text' ng-bind='monologues[session][0]'></div>
    <div class='timestamp' ng-bind='monologues[session][1] | to_locale'></div>
</div>
```

I specify a min-height for div.user (dynamically calculated with jQuery), and no height or margin for div.text or div.timestamp. Chrome's element inspector doesn't seem to turn up anything like a margin or min-height for div.text or div.timestamp. Manually specifying zero margin and min-height for div.user:

```
   <style type="text/css">
        div.user
            {
            overflow-y: auto !important;
            white-space: pre-wrap;
            }
        div.user div
            {
            margin: 0;
            min-height: 0;
            }
        input[type='text']
            {
            width: 100%;
            }
        textarea
            {
            width: 100%;
            height: 150px;
            }
    </style>
```

The page uses H5BP CSS, but commenting the includes on that file do not change the margins around the two inner div's to div.user.

Are there other things that could be giving me unwanted margin-like behavior?

Comment: What element has the unwanted white-space `div.user` or `div.text`?

Comment: div.text and div.timestamp both act as if they have unwanted whitespace; div.user scrolls as would be expected from those elements having unwanted whitespace. However, I haven't been able to find whitespace with Chrome's inspector.

Comment: You could try `font-size: 0` on `div.user` and see if that eliminates the unwanted white-space on child items.

Comment: What does your debugger of the browser say about those divs?

Comment: Have you tried it without `white-space: pre-wrap;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `white-space: pre-wrap;` is causing the issue

see http://jsfiddle.net/GVTr2/

Now this is with it

http://jsfiddle.net/GVTr2/1/

I don't know why you need it but as for your question, this is the cause

```
div.user {
    overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

If you really want to keep it, then you can have your html in one line like the below

```
<div class='user' ng-repeat='session in sessions'><div class='text' ng-bind='monologues[session][0]'>asfafd adsfds</div><div class='timestamp' ng-bind='monologues[session][1] | to_locale'>sdf sdf as</div></div>
```

OR

http://jsfiddle.net/GVTr2/2/

Defining `font-size: 0` for your parent and define a `font-size` for the children. This is not the ideal way to do things because this can get really messy real quick.

I think the best way is to not use pre-wrap